# arch linux installation, "could not create filesystems"

Tags: filesystems, install, arch-linux

im installing arch linux, the x86-64 net install.

during the part where the hard drive is being processed/erased, i get:
"Warning: Could not create all needed filesystems.
Either the underlying blockdevices didn't become available in 10 iterations, or process filesystem failed."

How do i fix that?
How do i know which filesystem to use?

Comment: What filesystem are you trying to use? Do you have appropriate drivers for your hard disks (if you have RAID, rare disks or something like that)? Are hard drives connected and functioning correctly (can you mount and read them in other shell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use another tool, like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), to set up your partitions and then return to the Arch installer and proceed with installing the packages and setting up the rest of your system.

In terms of the filesystems, the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Partition_Type) has a thorough section on what partitions you need (basically, you can get away with just `/`, but are better off with a minimum of `/` & `/home`) and the benefits and drawbacks of the filesystem types for each.